# Expand variable number of arguments in memory to argument space

Tags: mips, spim, mips64

I have a function that takes a memory address as `$a0` and I access the (variable) number of words by using `x($a0)`, where `x` is multiples of 8. I need to store these in the `$sp` register so I can use the `$a0` register for passing arguments to other functions. Completely new to MIPS assembly, so any pointers here would help!

Answer (score 0):

Multiples of 8 i assume you are using mips-64

first u make a loop and increment a0 by 8 each time:

```
loop: lw $t0, 0($a0)   ;fetch data and store in t0
      addi $sp,$sp,-8  ;increase stack
      sw $t0, 0($sp)   ;store data fetched
      addi $a0,$a0,8   ;increment a0 to go to next entry
;here you check that you haven't reached x yet
;let's say 8*x+$a0(initial) is stored in $t1 (this is easy to do just use sll by 3 to multiply by 8 then add a0 before loop)
      bne $a0,$t1,loop
;now you can use $a0
```